# Не выбирается прокси сервер из среза

Tags: golang

**У меня читается файл затем разбивается на строки, и далее должно выбираться рандомное значение, тоесть прокси-сервер.**

***Код:***

```
func randInt(len int) int {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().Unix())
    return rand.Intn(len)
}

func main() {
    bs, err := ioutil.ReadFile("proxy.txt")
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    str := string(bs)
    randoms := strings.Split(str, "\r\n")
    bestProxyServer := randInt(len(randoms))
    fmt.Print(randoms)

    proxyUrl, err := url.Parse(randoms[bestProxyServer])
    httpClient := &http.Client { Transport: &http.Transport { Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyUrl) } }
    response, err := httpClient.Get(host)
}
```

У меня выводится только срез строки и headers где указан мой обычный IP адрес:

```
[110.5.98.234:3128 110.8.253.100:80 113.6.255.107:80 114.30.47.10:80 114.30.79.62:8080 115.124.67.54:80 116.68.172.35:80
80 116.84.187.131:3128]map[Date:[Mon, 06 Nov 2017 15:59:37 GMT] Content-Type:[text/html; charset=UTF-8] Set-Cookie:[PHPS
ESSID=tknp6t8h5m6rmptdb8cvef1so2; path=/ IP%5B1509983977%5D=***82.34.213.181***; expires=Sun, 04-Feb-2018 15:59:37 GMT; Max-Ag
e=7776000; path=/; domain=.2ip.ru] Server:[nginx] Connection:[keep-alive] Expires:[Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT] Cache-
Control:[no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate] Pragma:[no-cache]]
```

Почему у меня не выбирается рандомный прокси сервер, а только **целый срез**?

Comment: В реальном коде ошибки проверяете? `fmt.Println(proxyUrl)` что показывает?

Comment: @Ainar-G fmt.Print(randoms[bestProxyServer]), я все же не внимательный, рандом работает, но почему то соединение с прокси севером не устанавливается.

Comment: Код выглядит нормально. Если вы вместо `httpClient.Get(host)` не написали `http.Get(host)`, то всё должно работать.

Comment: @Ainar-G да, метод httpClient.Get(host) написано

Answer (score 0):

Замените `fmt.Print(randoms)` на `fmt.Print(randoms[bestProxyServer])`.

Comment: Так, выводит уже другой IP адрес, тоесть все же рандом работает, но почему у меня не устанавливается соединение с прокси сервером?